# Install stuff in a schroot

Tags: linux, chroot

I have a question regarding chroots: say I have a program compiled and built into a root file tree structure, ex:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── software
├── etc
...
```

That is, to install this, I'd have to merge this with the root (/). Now, I've rsynced this into the chroot, but when I try to run it, I get error code 127 (no such file). Is there something else I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly interpreting what you wrote, I think you don't quite understand what chroot does. If I have a directory /mytemproot and mount on it a file system that has directories: bin, etc, sbin, foo, then I could:

```
% cd /mytemproot
% pwd
/mytemproot
% chroot /mytemproot
% pwd
/
% ls /
bin etc sbin foo
```

What chroot does is it puts you in a shell where /mytemproot is treated as if it were /. The real / is invisible to you as are all the other file systems under the real /. It does not merge the file systems.

Back in the old days, when the lowly sys-admins used to build each new UNIX distribution from scratch, we would make a new disk partition, put a file system on that partition and do the build and install in there. Then we would mount that file system somewhere, chroot to it and check everything out before we unleased it on the users. I should imagine that developers today use it much the same way.

Comment: Umm... I don't think that's exactly what I was asking. Basically: I **already** have a chroot and I just need to put some stuff into **its** filesystem, so I am merging these two trees (ie. when I have /home/user/software/bin and want to merge that into /home/user/chroot/bin) so that the chroot will now be able to see these files. Maybe my situation is a bit confusing :D But when I try to run this software that is now in /home/user/chroot/bin, it gives 127 :(

Comment: OK, obviously I missed the point. How did you merge the files? Copying the files over will work; linking won't; mounting should work but you said merge so that doesn't sound like what you did. My tired old brain needs some more guidance.

Comment: Lol, as I said, I `rsync -av`ed it

Comment: I'm really striking out today, aren't I? The only things I could think of were that the file failed to copy or the file was really a symbolic link, but those are things you would already have known and fixed. I looked up errno 127 and it actually means EKEYEXPIRED, which got me thinking - is it trying to get back to the old (pre-chroot and pre-rsync) location of the file? Then I had a crazy thought - have you tried running rehash (for csh, tcsh) or hash -r (for sh, bash) after you chroot? Or, if you haven't been using the fully qualified path to the command, could you try that?

Comment: Even if I use the full path it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Sigh. I'm sorry I wasn't able to help.

Comment: No problem, I'm not sure what's causing this either. Maybe I am just not getting something